# C - Populate a generic struct inside a function without malloc

Tags: c, generic-programming, void-pointers, c11

I'm trying to build a generic function that can populate a struct **without any dynamic memory allocation**.

The following code is a naive example of what I'm trying to do.
This code will not compile as `incomplete type 'void' is not assignable`.

Please note that this is a toy example to highlight my problems. I don't really want to convert colours; I just want to highlight that the structures will be different in data types and size.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} rgb_t;

typedef struct {
    float c;
    float m;
    float y;
    float k;
} cmyk_t;

typedef enum { RGB, CMYK } color_t;

void convert_hex_to_color(long hex, color_t colorType, void* const out) {
    if (colorType == RGB) {
        rgb_t temp = { 0 };
        // Insert some conversion math here....
        temp.r = 1;
        temp.g = 2;
        temp.b = 3;
        *out = temp; //< [!]
    } else
    if (colorType == CMYK) {
        cmyk_t temp = { 0 };
        // Insert some conversion math here....
        temp.c = 1.0;
        temp.m = 2.0;
        temp.y = 3.0;
        temp.k = 4.0;
        *out = temp; //< [!]
    }
}

int main(void) {
    // Given
    long hex = 348576;
    rgb_t mydata = { 0 };
    convert_hex_to_color(hex, RGB, (void*)(&mydata));

    // Then
    printf("RGB = %i,%i,%i\r\n", mydata.r, mydata.g, mydata.b);
    return 0;
}
```

For some additional context, I'm using C11 on an embedded system target.

What is the best[1] way to do this? Macro? Union?

Regards,
Gabriel

[1] I would define "best" as a good compromise between readability and safety.

Comment: Could use `*out = temp;` --> `memcpy(out, &temp, sizeof temp);` and let the compiler optimize for efficient emitted code.

Comment: Note; `convert_hex_to_color(hex, RGB, (void*)(&mydata));` --> cast not needed in C.

Comment: you could replace the first '*out = temp;' with '*(rgb_t*)out=temp;' and so on. As long as the void* is, in fact a pointer to the right type cast to a void* this will work,

Comment: @dmuir I think you want `*(rgb_t*)out=temp;`  (another `*`)

Comment: @chux Explicit cast (**to** a `void*`) not needed in C++, either.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. Even better that way. Are they not "enforced" by `-Wpedantic` or something like it?

Comment: No lack of enforcement.  C always allows `void *` to `some_object *` conversion.   What text or who suggested you should cast ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for the error is it is invalid to store via a `void` pointer: the compiler does not know what to store. You could cast the pointer as `*(rgb_t *)out = temp;` or `*(cmyk_t *)out = temp;`

Alternately, you could define `temp` as a pointer to the appropriate structure type and initialize it directly from `out`, without the cast that is not needed in C:

```
void convert_hex_to_color(long hex, color_t colorType, void *out) {
    if (colorType == RGB) {
        rgb_t *temp = out;
        // Insert some conversion math here....
        temp->r = 1;
        temp->g = 2;
        temp->b = 3;
    } else
    if (colorType == CMYK) {
        cmyk_t *temp = out;
        // Insert some conversion math here....
        temp->c = 1.0;
        temp->m = 2.0;
        temp->y = 3.0;
        temp->k = 4.0;
    }
}
```

Note that the cast is not needed in C:

```c
int main(void) {
    // Given
    long hex = 348576;
    rgb_t mydata = { 0 };
    convert_hex_to_color(hex, RGB, &mydata);

    // Then
    printf("RGB = %i,%i,%i\r\n", mydata.r, mydata.g, mydata.b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @bruno: much better indeed, although I am alone in the office surrounded by 110 empty seats. `{}` is indeed invalid as an initializer in C. `{0}` is valid and OK for all types, but a tad sloppy as it may trigger a warning for missing member initializers.

Comment: oh about {0} there is a similar remark on the other answer

Comment: +1 My apologies, I can't upvote yet. 
This is a great answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

```
rgb_t temp = {0};
```

So that declares a variable on the stack of type `rgb_t`. So far so good, <strike>though you don't need that 0</strike>.

```
*out = temp;
```

Here is your problem: in C you can only copy memory of the same type. Ever. This has nothing to do with `malloc`, as your title suggests, this is just the basic language specification. Sure, some types provide implicit casts, but `void*` is not one of them.

So if you're copying a structure (`rgb_t` on the right side), the destination *has to be of the same type*. So change the line to this:

```
*(rgb_t *)out = temp;
```

Comment: In C, you need that `0` — writing `{}` is not valid C, even if some C compilers accept it as an extension, influenced no doubt by the companion C++ compiler.

Comment: I stand corrected, I only really use MSVC and even then for C++.

Answer (score 4):

The "best" way is not to mix unrelated structures in the same function, or in the same memory area for that matter. That's just messy design.

If you need to keep a unison API for two different forms of data, then a typesafe function-like macro might be one idea. You can fake such a macro to have a syntax similar to passing the data by pointer

`void convert_hex_to_color(long hex, type* data)`

But then use C11 `_Generic` to actually determine the correct type to use, rather than using dangerous void pointers. Since you can't pass parameters "by reference" to macros, you'd have to sneak in a variable assignment in there. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} rgb_t;

typedef struct {
    float c;
    float m;
    float y;
    float k;
} cmyk_t;



void convert_hex_to_color(long hex, void* data);
  /* 
     Pretty prototype just for code documentation purposes. 
     Never actually defined or called - the actual macro will "mock" this function. 
  */

#define convert_hex_to_color(hex, output) ( *(output) = _Generic(*(output), \
  rgb_t:  (rgb_t){ .r=1, .g=2, .b=3 }, \
  cmyk_t: (cmyk_t){ .c=1.0, .m=2.0, .y=3.0, .k=4.0 } ) )


int main(void) {
    // Given
    long hex = 348576;
    rgb_t  myrgb  = { 0 };
    cmyk_t mycmyk = { 0 };

    convert_hex_to_color(hex, &myrgb);
    convert_hex_to_color(hex, &mycmyk);

    printf("RGB  = %i,%i,%i\r\n", myrgb.r, myrgb.g, myrgb.b);
    printf("CMYK = %f,%f,%f,%f\r\n", mycmyk.c, mycmyk.m, mycmyk.y, mycmyk.k);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
RGB  = 1,2,3
CMYK = 1.000000,2.000000,3.000000,4.000000
```

---

Just be aware that the `_Generic` support for type qualifiers (`const` etc) was shaky in C11 - some C11 compilers treated `const rgb_t` different from `rgb_t`, others treated them the same. This was one of the "bug fixes" in C17, so use C17 if available.

Comment: Thanks for the note on the C17 bugfix.  I've been curious what exactly was fixed by it.  Fortunately, since C17 was intended as a bugfix rather than a whole new standard, new enough versions of gcc and clang made `-std=c11` equivalent to `-std=c17` aside from the value `__STD_C_VERSION__` is set to.

Comment: I noticed that you did your `_Generic` selection based on the type being pointed to, rather than the type of the pointer.  Is there any benefit to doing it this way, or is purely a stylistic choice?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look out for C11 vs C17 problem.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Regarding C17, see [Jens Gustedt's blog](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2018/06/15/c17-rvalues-and-function-types-drop-qualifiers/). I do believe I was able to provoke the bug with _Generic not dropping type qualifiers on some compiler, but I don't remember which one. That is, code like `#define TEST(x) _Generic((x), int const: "foo", int : "bar")` compiling and preserving qualifier. In C17, the first operand of _Generic undergoes "lvalue conversion" and drops all qualifiers.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Regarding using a pointer, it doesn't matter for this example, but the reason is to make a special case for types with different qualifiers (regardless of C11 vs C17). Because C has stronger typing for pointers, `int*` and `const int*` are treated as different types. You can also use this trick to distinguish arrays from pointers (to the first element): `#define TEST(x) _Generic(&(x), char** : puts("pointer"), char(*)[]: puts("array"))`.

Answer (score 3):

Frame challenge: It seems like you want to perform a different operation depending on the type that you pass into this function.  Instead of using an enum to tell it what type you're passing in, and branching based on that enum, make use of C11's `_Generic` to handle that, and you don't even need to explicitly tell it what the type is on each call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
} rgb_t;

typedef struct {
    float c;
    float m;
    float y;
    float k;
} cmyk_t;

inline void convert_hex_to_color_rgb(long hex, rgb_t *const out) {
    (void) hex; // or whatever you're planning to do with 'hex'
    out->r = 1;
    out->g = 2;
    out->b = 3;
}

inline void convert_hex_to_color_cmyk(long hex, cmyk_t *const out) {
    (void) hex; // or whatever you're planning to do with 'hex'
    out->c = 1.0;
    out->m = 2.0;
    out->y = 3.0;
    out->k = 4.0;
}

#define convert_hex_to_color(hex, out) _Generic((out), \
        rgb_t *: convert_hex_to_color_rgb((hex), (rgb_t *)(out)), \
        cmyk_t *: convert_hex_to_color_cmyk((hex), (cmyk_t *)(out)) \
)

int main(void) {
    // Given
    long hex = 348576;
    rgb_t mydata = { 0 };
    cmyk_t mydatac = { 0 };
    convert_hex_to_color(hex, &mydata);
    convert_hex_to_color(hex, &mydatac);

    // Then
    printf("RGB = %i,%i,%i\r\n", mydata.r, mydata.g, mydata.b);
    printf("CMYK = %f,%f,%f,%f\r\n", mydatac.c, mydatac.m, mydatac.y, mydatac.k);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very interesting. This way you "detect" the correct version of the function we want to use.
As clever as this is, would you recommend it in production code? One could argue, that it makes the function less explicit. Also, are you aware of what _Generic implies in assembly call? Thanks again.

Comment: Ach, didn't see this answer before I posted a nearly identical one. Mine relies on macro expansion instead of inlining - inlining is definitely more suitable if the algorithm itself is complex, rather than just a bunch of assignments.

Comment: However, please note that inlining will give all manner of type qualifier hiccups, especially if you toss out a `type *const` API for no apparent reason. Suppose the caller passes a `const type*`. This is also problematic for _Generic itself in C11, I added a note about type qualifiers in my answer.

Comment: @gberth This is fine to use for production code, but the API to the "function" needs to be properly documented in comments, as if it was a regular function. In the header file, you can even declare a function prototype with the same name `void convert_hex_to_color(long hex, void* ptr)` or such, just for clarity (and to make "code completion" features in your IDE happy). Then have the macro "mock" that function, much like C standard lib functions are often implemented with macros instead of actual function calls. Regarding the assembly, you'll see nothing of _Generic, it's all compile-time.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, the functions look pretty basic, but I had gotten the impression that it was pared down to make an MCVE, hence the unused `hex` argument that I assume will be used for actually populating the struct members rather than literal assignments currently being used.

Comment: @gberth You might consider putting the macro name in all-caps to signify to any posterity reading the code that it is a macro rather than a proper function.  I just kept it as-is so that it plugged into your existing code (though I guess the removal of the enum argument required changes regardless).  If that doesn't make it explicit enough for your taste, it would be better to just have separate functions for the different types and call those rather than relying on an enum to identify the type and then branching based on that.

Comment: Why `static inline` and not just `inline`?

Comment: @gberth I think that may have just been reflex on my part as I typically have a slightly different use-case such that the "helper" functions have no reason to have external linkage.